# Getting value of a particular element within a particular div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the markup, i have several divs with same id and inside those divs there are paragraphs and buttons. Now when a button is clicked, i want to get the value of a corresponding paragraph tag under the same div as that particular button. How can i do this with jQuery? The markup is as followed:

```
<div class="col-sm-5 narrow">
    <p id="title">Jhon123</p>
    <p id="text">This is the status of jhon</p>
    <p>posted at 12:30pm GMT6+</p>
    <form class="form-inline">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reply" placeholder="Type and enter to reply">
        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default" id="repost">Re-Tweet</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

When the button with the id #repost is clicked, i want to access the html inside the p tag with the id #text. I tried something like this:

```
$('#retweet').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var text = $(this).parent("div").closest('#text');
    alert("some retweet button has been pressed which has the text:"+text);
});
```

Comment: Please post the jQuery/JS you tried. Oh, and IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: *i have several divs with same id* Then change the ids into classes. Ids should be unique.

Comment: what i meant is, several divs are generated in an iterative way while looping through and array of objects. so i cant just do a generic jquery to select some text inside a paragraph with #text id.

Comment: It doesn't really matter how the markup is generated. `id` values should be unique on the whole page. Use a `class` instead if you want to have the same one for multiple elements.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the jQuery `.closest()` function to get the containing `<div>` and then find the `<p>` tag you want inside it:

```
$('#repost').on('click', function () {
    var text = $(this).closest('div[class^=col]').find('#text').html();
    console.log(text);
});
```

The `div[class^=col]` selector means "find the closest `div` tag with a class starting with `col`". This allows you to use the other bootstrap column classes as well and have it still work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#repost').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).closest('div').find('#text').html());
  });
```

See demo http://jsbin.com/wojupoyosa/1/edit?html,js,console,output

and as comments suggest you IDs should be unique per page so you should use a class or something else instead.

Answer (score 0):

`$( "#text" ).text()` will give you the value inside P tag. So your code will look something like:

```
$('#repost').click(function(){
   $( "#text" ).text() // save it to wherever you want
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As a side note it is generally frowned upon to have css id's that are not unique - shared identifiers should use a class.

Answer (score 0):

If you change all your `id`s into classes as shown in the demo below, then the following code should work fine. Also, you do not need the form element.

```
$('.repost').click(function(){
    var text = $(this).closest('div').find('.text').text();
alert("some retweet button has been pressed which has the text: " + text);
});
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('.repost').click(function(){
        var text = $(this).closest('div').find('.text').text();
    alert("some retweet button has been pressed which has the text: " + text);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-5 narrow">
    <p class="title">Jhon123</p>
    <p class="text">This is the status of jhon</p>
    <p>posted at 12:30pm GMT6+</p>
    <form class="form-inline">
        <input type="text" class="form-control reply" placeholder="Type and enter to reply">
        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default repost">Re-Tweet</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5 narrow">
    <p class="title">Mary123</p>
    <p class="text">This is the status of mary</p>
    <p>posted at 12:35pm GMT6+</p>
    <form class="form-inline">
        <input type="text" class="form-control reply" placeholder="Type and enter to reply">
        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default repost">Re-Tweet</button>
    </form>
</div>
```